# Elastic Beanstalk can't enable nginx gzip

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm facing an issue with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and gzip.

I'm trying to enable Gzip compression and especially gzip compression for `application/javascript`. So, I tried to write two separately files.

The first one named `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` and I copy paste the content from the existing file which was in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder.

In the end of the file, I added the following lines of code:

`gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;`

then i created an another file named `gzip.conf` and i put this code:
and the other one `gzip.conf` :

`container_commands:
  enable_javascript_compress:
    command: sudo cp .ebextensions/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`

If I'm trying to upload and deploy those files which I saved them into `.ebextensions` folder the gzip is not working.

If I'm trying to edit this file from the server with ssh and vim everything works great.

Is there any way to fix it and not needs to connect every time with ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the gzip file using the `files` object. Here's what the start of one of my nginx confs look:

```
files:
  /tmp/install-nginx-conf.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      cp /tmp/nginx_proxy.conf 
/tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```